# Отскакивающий от дива мячик

Tags: javascript, функции, анимация, таймер

Нужно, чтобы мячик отскакивал от синего дива, а не проходил сквозь него

```js
    var ballH={
        posX : 30,
        posY : 30,
        speedX : Math.random()*(20 + 10) - 10,
        speedY : Math.random()*(20 + 10) - 10,
        width : 50,
        height: 50,

        update : function() {
            var ballElem=document.getElementById('IBall');
            ballElem.style.left=this.posX+"px";
            ballElem.style.top=this.posY+"px";
        }
    }

    var areaH={
        width : 400,
        height : 300
    }

    function start() {
        // плавное движение - от 25 кадр/сек
        setInterval(tick,40);
    }

    function tick() {

        ballH.posX+=ballH.speedX;
        // вылетел ли мяч правее стены?
        if ( ballH.posX+ballH.width>areaH.width ) {
            ballH.speedX=-ballH.speedX;
            ballH.posX=areaH.width-ballH.width;
        }
        // вылетел ли мяч левее стены?
        if ( ballH.posX<0 ) {
            ballH.speedX=-ballH.speedX;
            ballH.posX=0;
        }

        ballH.posY+=ballH.speedY;
        // вылетел ли мяч ниже пола?
        if ( ballH.posY+ballH.height>areaH.height ) {
            ballH.speedY=-ballH.speedY;
            ballH.posY=areaH.height-ballH.height;
        }
        // вылетел ли мяч выше потолка?
        if ( ballH.posY<0 ) {
            ballH.speedY=-ballH.speedY;
            ballH.posY=0;
        }

        ballH.update();
    }

    ballH.update();
```

```html
<input type='button' value='Пуск!' onclick='start()'>
<br /><br />
<div style='width: 400px; height: 300px;
    border: solid blue 1px; position: relative'>
    <div  id='IBall'
         style='position: absolute;width:40px;height:40px;background-color: red;border-radius: 50%'>
    </div>
    <div style="height:110px;width:25px;background-color:blue;position:absolute; right:0; top:150px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Выглядит как требование сделать задание за вас. У вас уже есть код для обработки столкновений, в чём оказались трудности дописать его?

Comment: нужно просто добавить еще условий по аналогии со стенами.